# How do I grep multiple lines (output from another command) at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep

I have a Linux driver running in the background that is able to return the current system data/stats. I view the data by running a console utility (let's call it **dump-data**) in a console. **All** data is dumped every time I run **dump-data**. The output of the utility is like below

```
Output:
- A=reading1
- B=reading2
- C=reading3
- D=reading4
- E=reading5
...
- variableX=readingX
...
```

The list of readings returned by the utility can be really long. Depending on the scenario, certain readings would be useful while everything else would be useless.

I need a way to grep only the useful readings whose names might have have nothing in common (via a bash script). I.e. Sometimes I'll need to collect A,D,E; and other times I'll need C,D,E.

I'm attempting to graph the readings over time to look for trends, so I can't run something like this:

```
# forgive my pseudocode
Loop
    dump-data | grep A
    dump-data | grep D
    dump-data | grep E
End Loop
```

to collect A,D,E as that would actually give me readings from 3 separate calls of dump-data as that would not be accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to save all result of grep in the same file, you can just join all expressions in one:

```
grep -E 'expr1|expr2|expr3'
```

But if you want to have results (for expr1, expr2 and expr3) in separate files, things are getting more interesting.

You can do this using `tee >(command)`.

For example, here I process the same pipe with thre different commands:

```
$ echo abc | tee >(sed s/a/_a_/ > file1) | tee >(sed s/b/_b_/ > file2) | sed s/c/_c_/ > file3
$ grep "" file[123]
file1:_a_bc
file2:a_b_c
file3:ab_c_
```

But the command seems to be too complex.

I would better save `dump-data` results to a file and then grep it.

```
TEMP=$(mktemp /tmp/dump-data-XXXXXXXX)
dump-data > ${TEMP}
grep A ${TEMP}
grep B ${TEMP}
grep C ${TEMP}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! grep -E worked fine. I selected your answer as it offered a little more than the rest. I did think of your last solution, but as I might take readings pretty often it might be a little inefficient.

Comment: yes of course, but when you need separate output files for each expression, it is inevitable :) when not, of course, not :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dump-data | grep -E "A|D|E"`. Note the `-E` option of grep. Alternatively you could use `egrep` without the `-E` option.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use:

```
dump-data | grep -E 'A|D|E'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/MY PATTERN/{print > "matches-"FILENAME;}' myfile{1,3}
```

thx [Guru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/24501/guru) at [Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55298/output-multiple-files-from-a-single-grep/55302#55302)